# Is there a workaround for choosing what visuals are affected by drill-through in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, drillthrough

I have 3 tables:

1. **Application**: that shows information about the application including [Type], [Status], [Stage], etc...
2. **Stakeholders**: that shows information about various stakeholders including [Location], [Email], [Type], etc...
3. **Roles**: that uses two lookup columns to the 'Application' & 'Stakeholders' tables, that shows what role a stakeholder has for an application

I have a Power BI dashboard that shows 'Application' details (i.e. Type, status, etc...) including a list of the stakeholders that have a role for that application. I have a drill-through that allows users to pick a stakeholder from that list, and 'drill-through' to a 'Stakeholder' dashboard showing the chosen stakeholders details (i.e. what roles they have for various applications).

Within that 'Stakeholder' page I would like a search filter where I can change what stakeholder details I am looking at, without going back to the 'Application' dashboard to drill-through. This will allow a user to see all applications a stakeholder has a role in.

I am unsure how to approach this. I've read some people would duplicate the column they don't want drill-through, but not really sure how that solves it.

I've also tried creating a measure with the ALL function but receive this error:

```
Calculation error in measure 'Application'[Search]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.
```

If anyone has any work around, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you update your question and elaborate on: "Within that 'Stakeholder' page I would like a search filter where I can change what stakeholder details I am looking at." Are you looking to switch or show other stakeholders?

Comment: I have made some edits. Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Comment: Can you share a link to sample PBIX?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, as it contains sensitive data.

Comment: Create a very basic example PBIX that demonstrates the need/ask.